# Route resolver with RxJs pipe does not trigger ngOnInit of component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to resolve a route using the ResolverSevice which should eventually trigger the ngOnInit of the HomePage component. The route solver basically redirects conditionally which re-triggers the resolver to retrieve some page data.

The problem however is that the route resolver does not seem to trigger the ngOnInit of the component.

```
export class ResolverService implements Resolve<Observable<Page>> {

  constructor(
    private readonly httpClient: HttpClient,
    private readonly ngRedux: NgRedux<any>,
    private readonly router: Router,
  ) {}

  private homeConfig: {
    [key: string]: string;
  } = {
    en: '/en/home',
    fr: '/fr/home',
    es: '/es/home',
  };
  
  private redirectUrls: string[] = [
    ...Object.values(this.homeConfig),
    '/home',
    '/',
  ];
  
  resolve(
    _route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<Page> {
    return this.ngRedux.select(state => state.language).pipe(
      switchMap((language: string) => {
        const homeUrl = this.homeConfig[language];
        if (this.redirectUrls.some(value => value === state.url) &&
          state.url !== homeUrl
        ) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl(homeUrl);
          // And return an empty observable (so don't fetch a page data)
          return EMPTY;
        }
        return this.httpClient
          .get<Page>('/api/pages/', {
            params: {
              requestPath: state.url.split('?')[0],
            },
          });
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomePage,
    resolve: {
      page: ResolverService,
    },
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PageRoutingModule {}
```

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('test');
    }
}
```

The curious thing is that the above setup does work when the RxJs pipe is removed (see below code sample). However, I do need the pipe as this one supplies a parameter from the NgRedux store used for the navigation itself.

```
resolve(
  _route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<Page> {
  const homeUrl = this.homeConfig['en'];
  if (this.redirectUrls.some(value => value === state.url) &&
    state.url !== homeUrl
  ) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(homeUrl);
    // And return an empty observable (so don't fetch a page data)
    return EMPTY;
  }
  return this.httpClient
    .get<Page>('/api/pages/', {
      params: {
        requestPath: state.url.split('?')[0],
      },
    });
}
```

I am wondering why the ngOnInit is not triggered by the HomePage component with the piped example?

Comment: Could you try to return something else than `EMPTY`

Comment: What do you mean by failure of navigateByUrl, does it not redirect to homepage component, are there any console errors?

Comment: @Batajus what would you suggest instead?

Comment: is it possible to add the PageComponent and Home Component code snippets to your question?

Comment: @RiteshWaghela I had another look, and rephrased my question. The navigateByUrl re-triggers the route resolve for the second time which then returns the Page data to the resolver as observable. But for some reason the ngOnInit of the HomePage component is simply not triggered.

Comment: @user3929590 I have added the HomePage component to the original question. It's empty for now, just contains an ngOnInit.

Comment: @Christophe the thing is that the resolver is running in loop because whenever it will go to home component, it will run the resolve method again. So whenever the condition is evaluating to true it redirects to home component and since there is a resolver for home component, it will run again.

Comment: @RiteshWaghela, the condition potentially evaluates to true on the first iteration. But the second evaluations always evaluates to false. So that is not problem I think. Also note that the entire setup works if I remove the RxJs pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .select of NgRedux actually never completes, hence remains active and the resolve function does not return.

Using .first() or take(1) will take the first value and complete the observable.